# Remove https://{site}.tld from Google

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, google-index, multiple-domains

I maintain a client's website, and at the beginning he insisted that he wanted two tld extensions on the same website (.gr and .com). I thought it was weird, but not having any idea on what was about to happen I agreed to make it as the client wanted.

After weeks of struggling with Google not indexing my page, I found out that Google does not like duplicate pages, which happened because I had both properties of https gr and https com pointing to the same site.

I made the gr domain (http) to redirect to https .com so that this would fix the issue. Right now, Google has indexed the https gr domain, even though I have deleted the property from Search Console, which domain does not work at all (following the link leads to an error). How can I make Google forget the https gr domain?

Comment: Deleting the site from search console just deletes your access to the data there, but has no bearing on whether or not Google indexes the site.   Google indexes many websites that have *never* been claimed by their owners via search console.

Comment: When you say you redirected it, how long did you then wait?   It could take Google a few months to de-index all the pages that have been redirected.  Should be faster for a small site.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want the https version to lead to an error. This will cause you to lose all of the page authority that the .gr domain has on https.

Instead, you want to 301 redirect all versions of you website to the main version. You can do this in either htaccess or through your domain management panel in your registrar (as most registar's provide this).

Here are some examples of 301 redirecting an entire domain to a new domain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain

You can also set all of the pages on the .gr domain to rel=canonical pointing to the .com domain address, but I think the 301 redirect is likely preferred in your situation if you have no intention of using the .gr domain anymore.

301 redirecting will preserve 90-100% of your domain/page authority and link juice when passing the .gr domain onto the .com domain.

Comment: I asked the registrar if we should redirect from https to https but they said that it is not possible, only from http to https. Forgot to mention that this is a rails app hosted on heroku. From what I understand so far, I should make the change again in the registrar as it was to point to the app in gr https, but through the app to redirect every page to the new domain.